# TypeError: must be str, not int in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to submit some emails in a website form. I use selenium with python 3.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import time
import getpass
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

while True:
    chromedriver  = 'F:\All  Folders\chromedriver\chrome.exe'

#Uncomment this block if you don't want images to load(makes the procss a little bit faster)
    '''
    chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
    '''

    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
    browser.get("http://www.website.com")       # website's home page
    time.sleep(10)

    # Logging into website
    form = browser.find_element_by_class_name('regular_login')
    email = form.find_element_by_name("email")
    password = form.find_element_by_name("password")
    button_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@value='Login']")

    #List of emails
    email_list = ['na23b9@gmail.com', '25g65b@gmail.si', 'gfdebfk@gmail.jp']
    for emails, emails in enumerate(email_list):
      email.send_keys(emails)
      emails = emails + 1
      print("success")
```

My plan is to submit each email in each browser session using while loop. But this line 'emails = emails + 1' returns error.

Here's the trackback:

```
 F:\Python_Installer\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Quora_Bot/westing.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Quora_Bot/westing.py", line 39, in <module>
    emails = emails + 1
TypeError: must be str, not int

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have no idea. Can someone kindly explain me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from

```
for emails, emails in enumerate(email_list):
  emails = emails + 1
```

First, but this is not what's causing the error, either use `for i, emails in enumerate(email_list)` and do something of the `i` counter, or simply use `for emails in email_list` if you only need the contents of the list.

Secondly, drop the `emails = emails + 1` : at this step, you are trying to add `1` (an integer) to `emails` (a string), which causes the error, and seems to serve no purpose whatsoever, since the very next step of your loop is to reassign a value to `emails` due to it being your iterator.

So, if what you want to do is to iterate over your list of emails so as to send them one by one, just do:

```
for email_adress in email_list:
    email.send_keys(email_adress)
```

I hope this helps.

*Post-Scriptum*:

As is, your code will run an infinite loop, which is something you do not want. There are cases when running an infinite loop while using `break` statements is very useful, but you seem to have nothing of the sort here ; additionally, as you seem to be trying to iterate over sessions, all you need are nested `for` loops.

Comment: First of very thank you @Archeo for your detailed answer. but              `for email_adress in enumerate(email_list):
   email.send_keys(email_adress)` didn't works and sends       
  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Quora_Bot/westing.py", line 30, in <module>
    email.send_keys(email_adress)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 348, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: then i tried:                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                     `for i, emails in enumerate(email_list):                                                     email.send_keys(email_adress)`

Comment: In the first case, it's my fault: I mistyped my answer (which is now corrected). As you want to iterate over the list's content, you should not use the `enumerate` function (please read the docs to understand why): `for email_adress in email_list:    email.send_keys(email_adress)`.

Comment: In the second case, it's because you are referring to the non-existing `email_adress` variable : if you wanted to use the count iterator `i`, you would do `for i, email_adress in enumerate(email_list):    email.send(email_adress)`. Please understand what your variables are, otherwise your code can only be messy, broken and hard to read (no offense, this is just a fact, not a judgement or an attack on your coding skills).

Comment: Thank you so much @Archeo for your time. but unfortunately both of them didn't worked. because they submit all the emails into the form. But i found another way that uses text file. I will create a blog post about it and will link from here. Once again, Thanks so much.